# Run function aynchronously in server asp vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I am developing a web application in asp.Net(VB). I am trying for some calculations on a button click.The calculation takes almost 30 min to complete .

I need to make the process independent; that means i will click the button and the process should start in the server so that I can close the page itself. Please advise me a propee approch to achieve this .

Comment: Great! What have you tried?

Comment: a webservice function. But not sure it gonna work as expected.

Comment: Take a look at Process.Start http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx If you don't mean that you want a truly separate process, take a look at threading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [Parallel Task Libray](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/518856/Task-Parallel-Library-and-async-await-Functionalit).

First of all, you have to do the calculations not in the click event handler but in a separate async function and call that inside the click event. This way you don't block the Page Life Cicle.

```
Private Sub MyButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyButton.Click
    DoSomeCalculations(Params)
End Sub

Private Async Sub DoSomeCalculations(Params)
    'Do stuff
End Sub
```

If you intend to publish the app to Azure, take a look at [Azure WebJobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/). It is the best solution for your case scenario.

Anyway... can I ask what kind of calculations take half an hour?